Number of days between two dates excluding Sunday in Google Sheets
For example, there are 14 days in total between 02.12.2024 and 16.12.2024 (excluding 02.12.2024, including 16.12.2024), but there are only 12 days excluding Sundays.
How can I calculate the number of days excluding Sundays between two dates in Google Sheets?


You may try with the following syntax:
=networkdays.intl(start_date+1; end_date; 11)


11 = Sunday is the only weekend

